# DeepLearning4j and DataVec read csv file with label

Tags: deeplearning4j

I have built a DL4j project. Everything is fine if I use MNIST dataset as follows:

```
    DataSetIterator mnistTrain = new MnistDataSetIterator(batchSize, true, rngSeed);
    DataSetIterator mnistTest = new MnistDataSetIterator(batchSize, false, rngSeed);
```

However, I want to switch to my own csv file with the following format:

```
A  |  B  |  C  |  X  |  Y
-------------------------
1  | 100 |  5  |  15 |  6
...
```

`X` and `Y` are the outcomes (or labels). As I plan to perform regression analysis, so both `X` and `Y` are real numbers. So I read the csv file using the following code:

```
    RecordReader recordReaderTrain = new CSVRecordReader(1, ",");
    recordReaderTrain.initialize(new FileSplit(new File("src/main/resources/data/Data.csv")));
    DataSetIterator dataIterTrain = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReaderTrain, batchSize, 3, 2);
```

`3` in the code means `index of the labels` and `2` means `number of possible labels`. There no much explanation about these two parameters. I guess they mean the labels start from the 4th column and has 2 labels.

When I run the code, it shows the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14
```

I think it is because dl4j does not recognize `15` as label.

So my question is: how can I properly read the csv file for a regression analysis?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so we have examples for regression:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/cc383de91bdf4e28e36859aa2e8749100cd63177/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/feedforward/regression

You need to pass regression true (it's an extra part of the constructor) to the RecordReaderDataSetIterator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works fine. 

May I ask another question. How can I convert the DataSet in the DataSetIterator into a `5` by `3` graph like input so that I can use Convolution network?

Comment: Mind posting a second question with more details? Thanks!